# how do I add 3 points randomly to a list?

Tags: list, random

I have a list below community_card_suit, and I want to randomly add 3 points to any of the indexes, so for example the outcome looks like [0,3,0,0] or [0,1,1,1] or [1,2,1,0], etc.

```
community_cards_suit = [0,0,0,0]
```

Any idea how I would do this randomly?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] and tag a language. [tag:python]?

Comment: It seems that you want to `replace` instead of `add`?

Comment: Regardless of language, is this not a matter of adding 1 three times? Pick a random index and increment the value, loop 3 times, done.